# Do I have to go through immigration for a connection in Canada (Montreal)?

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, canada, airports

I plan on flying from the US to Europe (Schengen) through Montreal airport (Trudeau Airport, YUL). The flights US-Montreal and Montreal-Europe are two different bookings. For the sake of simplicity, let's say I do not have any checked-in luggage.

According to the [website of the airport](http://www.admtl.com/en/guide/connecting-flights), if I connect from USA towards a non-US international destination with automatic luggage transfer (or no checked-in luggage), I have to "go to the special international connections customs counter". But does that involve only customs or also immigration? I am particularly interested in knowing if my passport will be checked, if that makes sense.

So, do I have to go through some form of immigration/passport check when connecting in Montreal from the US to Europe?

Comment: Most likely it will be checked at least for ID purposes. I find that passport is checked for everything at the airport (Toronto). You should call the airport to confirm exactly what they will check, there is a 1-800 number at the bottom of their site

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You and your passport and your boarding pass will be checked by [Canadian border security](http://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/menu-eng.html), as they're the ones who run the "[special international connections customs counter](http://www.admtl.com/en/guide/connecting-flights)".  They need to verify you are actually departing from YUL to the EU.

The airport's [maps](http://www.admtl.com/sites/default/files/ADM-Carte-ArriveesDeparts.pdf) don't actually show the counter, but there's [plenty of](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/19426031-post3.html) [first-hand](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/19481859-post8.html) [accounts](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/15856183-post6.html) [about it](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/15862892-post9.html).